# Multiple Jenkins parameterized build value pass value to Jenkinsfile for declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Hi my Jenkins project is parameterised build. I have 3 variables. 1 choice and 2 string parameter. The choise perameter is do_you_want_to_deploy and string parameter is git_tag and git_branch. I want to know how can i pass this value to a jenkinsfile?

In freestyle project, I selecft 'Extra Variables' and then got Key and Value. So key i put deploy_location, value is ${do_you_want_to_deplo}. Key is which_tag, value is ${git_tag}. Key is which_ranch, value is ${git_branch}. I am performing for ansible. How can i add verbos -vvv as well? This for pipelin project. Below is my code

```
                ansiblePlaybook(
                    vaultCredentialsId: 'VaultId',
                    inventory: 'host-inventory.yml',
                    playbook: 'myPlaybook.yml'
                )
``

I also need pass same value to downstream project. How can this be done?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hi my Jenkins project is parameterised build. I have 3 variables. 1
> choice and 2 string parameter. The choise perameter is
> do_you_want_to_deploy and string parameter is git_tag and git_branch.
> I want to know how can i pass this value to a jenkinsfile?

In Jenkinsfile there is [parameters block](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#available-parameters) to define variables. As per your use case, parameters definition may look like below. Here, by choice in your explanation I was assuming you need a toggle but if you need a list of items then use `choice` parameter type.

```
pipeline {
...
  parameters {
    booleanParam(name: 'do_you_want_to_deploy', defaultValue: false, description: 'Description of do_you_want_to_deploy')
    string(name: 'git_tag', defaultValue: '', description: 'Description of git_tag')
    string(name: 'git_branch', defaultValue: '', description: 'Description of git_branch')
  }
  stages {
    stage('Example') {
      steps {
        ansiblePlaybook(
          ...
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> In freestyle project, I selecft 'Extra Variables' and then got Key and
> Value. So key i put deploy_location, value is ${do_you_want_to_deplo}.
> Key is which_tag, value is ${git_tag}. Key is which_ranch, value is
> ${git_branch}. I am performing for ansible. How can i add verbos -vvv
> as well?

Ansible plugin has an option `extraVars` that can be used to pass number of variables from the pipeline. There is another option named `extras` that takes a string and can be used to pass additional variables, switches etc.

Together, `ansiblePlaybook` may look like below,

```
ansiblePlaybook (
  vaultCredentialsId: 'VaultId',
  inventory: 'host-inventory.yml',
  playbook: 'myPlaybook.yml',
  extras: '-vvv',
  extraVars: [
    deploy_location: params.do_you_want_to_deploy,
    which_tag: params.git_tag,
    which_branch: params.git_branch
  ]
)
```

> I also need pass same value to downstream project. How can this be
> done?

As you can see from the example of `ansiblePlaybook` above, the parameters can be accessed via `params` object.